# Proof of equilateral triangle given angles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Let's say we start with a scalene triangle ABC, with no given angle measures or side lengths:

[image: Triangle ABC]

Then, we add 3 Isosceles triangles adjacent to this one, given that they have angle measures 30*30*120, but no side lengths:

[image: Triangle with adjacent isosceles]

The question is, how would one go about proving that triangle Alpha-Beta-Gamma is equilateral?:

[image]

I've been working on this for quite some time now, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It reminds me of  Fermat/Toricelli point of a triangle.. Also the yellow triangle is not drawn to good proportion.

Comment: The "top" vertices of the isosceles triangles on each edge are the *centers* of *equilateral* triangles on each edge. That these points for an equilateral triangle is [Napoleon's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon's_theorem).

Comment: @Blue thank you so much for that, I can't believe I didn't realize it... that puts me on my way to solving it